# Multiple buttons on an Image

Tags: image, button

I am trying to create an interactive map that when you click a room, you get send to a more detail of it. I am struggling to put multiple buttons on an image as well as have them line up with the image properly. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: This is, I’m afraid, entirely too vague and broad as posted. Perhaps you could give us an example of what you have done so far.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Could you be more specific in your question? Please share the code you are working on. Only [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are likely to get great answers. Your question is currntly [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because in its current form is [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). To rever that please [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Also consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

Actually, any button is an image. Therefore, you can create graphics background and put the button on it using `Epilog->Inset[..]` . The insets could be easy arranged according to certain coordinates within the background graphics as below:

```
bcol = Orange;
Graphics[{Gray, EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 40}]}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Button["test", Print["!!"]], {70, 10}], 
   Inset[Dynamic@Button["ToRed", bcol = Red, Background -> bcol], {20,35}]}]
```

[image]

Buttons are nicely working..